# Why do I have 55 local area connections in ipconfig?

Tags: windows-vista, ipconfig

Windows Vista Home Premium. I should mention that I am having no problem whatever getting an internet connection.

When I type "ipconfig" in the console, I get (55!) messages of 3 lines each, listing a ton of disconnected network connections. My PC only has one network card. Each message looks like this:

```
Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 55:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

These don't cause a major problem; they make it a pain, though, to fish upward and find my IP address. How can I get rid of them?

**Edit:**

Actually, a few connection numbers are randomly missing from the sequence; so, it's really more like 30 or 40 connection messages, rather than all 55. Not sure why that is, either.

Comment: Do you have a cheap external network adapter, like a 3G modem or phone?

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your question and suddenly noticed something uncommon,
 that was the `*` with the name. Googled a little and found this answer
 on MSFT forum.

> Windows makes several "simulated" network adapters for various
>   purposes. For example, if you're on an IPv4-only network, but you want
>   to connect to an IPv6 computer on the internet, Windows can create a
>   simulated network adapter that tunnels the IPv6 traffic through your
>   IPv4 network.
>
> There are actually quite a few of these simulated
>   network adapters.  Since they usually quietly take care of themselves,
>   and they don't correspond to any actual network hardware that you (the
>   end-user) can see or touch, Windows will hide them by default, to
>   avoid clutter.
>
> Now suppose Windows just started numbering all the
>   adapters with the same naming scheme ("Ethernet 1", "Ethernet 2",
>   "Ethernet 3", . . ., etc.).  Then by the time you actually install
>   your actual NIC, it would probably get a name like "Ethernet 7".  But
>   since Windows hides the first 6 network interfaces, you'd see a
>   listing that only includes one NIC: "Ethernet 7".  And you'd probably
>   say "stupid Windows doesn't know how to count."
>
> So instead, we have
>   two numbering schemes.  Real, physical NICs get numbered "Ethernet
>    ###" (or "Wi-Fi ###", etc.) while all the hidden network adapters get "Local Area Connection* ###".  That way, the NICs that you see will be
>   numbered starting from 1, even though there are a big pile of hidden
>   network interfaces that were installed first.
>
> What does the asterisk
>   mean?  The asterisk used to be the signal that the NIC was a hidden
>   NIC.  Older versions of Windows named all visible NICs "Local Area
>   Connection ###", and hidden ones were distinguished by adding an extra
>   asterisk.  These days, we try to avoid using nerdy jargon like "Local
>   Area Connection" when talking to you, so we changed the naming pattern
>   to "Ethernet".  But since hidden NICs don't matter, we kept their old
>   naming pattern with the asterisk.
>
> If you're curious, you can see all
>   the network interfaces on your system with this PowerShell command:
>
> ```
> Get-NetAdapter -IncludeHidden
> ```

*([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/66d50eb2-c429-4b1a-8e7a-020a45c93068/what-does-the-local-area-connection-12-mean?forum=w8itpronetworking))*

This not only explains the `*` but also explains your 55 connections. The `*` connections are simulated.

Answer (score 0):

These are probably IPv6 Tunnel Adapters. While I haven't seen it myself, I've heard of others who seem to get a new one for every new network they connect to. If you don't need IPv6, you can disable it, and remove the redundant tunnel adapters. There's a post here about it:

http://ryanvictory.com/posts/automating-6to4-adapter-removal-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

At a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:

> set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1

Then go to Control Panel > System > Device Manager > View > Show Hidden Devices > Network adapter>

Remove all ISATAP Devices and Microsoft 6TO4 Adapters.

Turn off IPV6 on your adapter:

[image]

Comment: All the steps above were relevant, but did not solve this problem for me. (I have just one extra `* 9` adapter.)